# filling a Mat Plot Lib Scatter plot with points using a loop

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

[image]

I tried this but got an error that they are not the same size

```
x = np.linspace(0,501,num=50)
y = np.linspace(0,501,num=50)

for i in range(10,510,10):
    
    plt.scatter(x,i,c='dimgrey')
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_facecolor('darkgrey')
    plt.xlim(0,501)
    plt.ylim(0,501);
```

My overall goal is to have N amount of points plotted in a grid orientation in the scatter plot.  I was tying to plot 2500 points like this.
All I could come up with was one row or column would equal 50 points,
and I made this loop.

I want to fill the plot like this: a line of points at y= 10 as I have here, then at 20,30,40... so on.  I realize I could do this manually but is there an easier way I could incorporate it into the loop? I am planning on putting it into an animation later.

Comment: Please do not post image of your code but the code itself using the formatting. This will allow users to reproduce your example in order to help you.

Comment: In your code **y** is never used. You dont need to loop over **x** elements since it's an array. You should better iterate over the **y** values you want for each plot.

Comment: I tried this but it gave me an error saying x and y weren't the same size.        `column = 50 
x = np.linspace(0,501,num=50)
y = np.linspace(0,501,num=50)

for i in range(10,510,10):
    
    plt.scatter(x,i,c='dimgrey')
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_facecolor('darkgrey')
    plt.xlim(0,501)
    plt.ylim(0,501);          `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an simple example, starting from your code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,501,num=50)

for i in range(10,40,10):
    y = i * np.ones(50)
    plt.scatter(x,y)
```

This gives the following plot :

[image: scatter plot]